# Need a multi user voice chat application that can be integrated into rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, chat, voice

Is there is any rails plugin that can be used for voice chat between multiple users?
OR
 multi user voice chat application in any other language that can be integrated with rails application?

Eagerly waiting for help.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there's always the possibility to use any of the [available FOSS VoIP solutions](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Open+Source+VOIP+Software). I'm not aware of any that have Ruby plugin capabilities out-of-the-box, but you could always write the plugin yourself. Most of them are very well documented, and reference implementations exist for a number of languages.